# ConcurrentModificationException in iterator.next()

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have next code in background thread

```
private List<IStartAction> mActions = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<IStartAction>()); 

protected void removeNonApplicableActions() {
        Iterator<IStartAction> iterator = mActions.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            IStartAction action = iterator.next();
            if (!action.isApplicable()) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

When i run this in main thread got ConcurrentModificationException into iterator.next().
Why is this happening? I use thread-safe collection and remove items through iterator. Collection used in only this thread.

Comment: synchronized means that you can modify list in more than 1 thread under specific conditions (please see javadoc for synchronizedList() method). Here is a different issue, you are iterating and removing at the same time. Please use listIterator instead of plain iterator. Use listIterator() method.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example of your code so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` isn't _necessarily_ indicating you have multiple threads modifying your list, it's that you are concurrently iterating through your list and modifying it at the same time.

Comment: This seems weird/buggy.  MCVE please.

Comment: What does `isApplicable()` do? Does it modify `mActions` in any way?

Comment: Yeah, something is touching mActions w/o going through that iterator, I bet.  I tried the best I could to replicate this, and Collections.synchronizedMap's iterator works.

Comment: Note that just because the list is synchronized, does not mean that the *iteration* is thread safe. As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) says, you need to manually synchronize that.

Comment: isApplicable() not modify mActions. Method return true/false(hardcode)
I thought to use synchronized block,
but I thought it was strange. Because I use a thread-safe collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread safety for a synchronized collection only applies to one method call. Between method calls the lock is released and another thread can lock the collection. If you perform two operations, anything could happen in the meantime, unless you lock it your self. e.g.

```
// to add two elements in a row, you must hold the lock.
synchronized(mAction) {
    mAction.add(x);
    // without holding the lock, anything could happen in between
    mAction.add(y);
}
```

Similarly to iterate over a synchronized collection, you have to hold the lock, otherwise anything could happen between method calls to the iterator.

```
synchronized (mAction) {
    for(Iterator<IStartAction> iter = mActions.iterator(); iter.hashNext();) {
        IStartAction action = iter.next();
        if (!action.isApplicable()) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```